# Validation html selects (javascript or jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have multiple rows of 3 equal selects in each row. I am looking for a way so that selects in a row cant be repeated.

```
<tr  align='center'>
<input type="hidden" name="codialum[]" value="314" />
<td><input type='text' name='al1[]' id='al1[]' value='Student1' /></td> 
<td> <select name="optativa1[]" id="optativa1">
        <option value=43>Opt. Anglès</option>
        <option value=44>Opt. Biologia</option>
        ...
        ...
     </select>
</td>
<td> <select name="optativa2[]" id="optativa2">
        <option value=43>Opt. Anglès</option>
        <option value=44>Opt. Biologia</option>
        ...
        ...
     </select>
</td>
<td> <select name="optativa3[]" id="optativa3">
        <option value=43>Opt. Anglès</option>
        <option value=44>Opt. Biologia</option>
        ...
        ...
     </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr  align='center'>
<input type="hidden" name="codialum[]" value="315" />
<td><input type='text' name='al1[]' id='al1[]' value='Student2' /></td> 
<td> <select name="optativa1[]" id="optativa1">
        <option value=43>Opt. Anglès</option>
        <option value=44>Opt. Biologia</option>
        ...
        ...
```

[image]

It could be done after post, but I would like to do in browser. 
I made some unsuccessful attempts

Thanks

Comment: *"It could be done after post, but I would like to do in browser."* - It should be done server-side even if you also do it in the browser, to allow for users who use dev tools to bypass client-side validation. Anyway, do you mean that separate rows may have the same selected value(s), but within a single row the three values must be different? Or that *all* values in all rows must be different?

Comment: Yes, I will check server side too. Every student must  have 3 diferent subjects ( lets say, maths, sciences, and english) 2 or more students can have that subjects but a single student cant have 2 maths...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little something like this:

```js
// attach a submit handler to your form (I've used a button click
// for this demo because the stack snippet sandbox didn't seem to like
// a form submitting, but you should use form submit)
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", validate);

function validate(e) {
  var allOK = true;
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr");        // get a reference to all rows
  var subjects;

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {            // loop over the rows
    subjects = rows[i].querySelectorAll("select");   // get a reference to the
    if (subjects[0].value === subjects[1].value ||   // selects in the current
        subjects[0].value === subjects[2].value ||   // row and test their values
        subjects[1].value === subjects[2].value) {
      allOK = false;                                 // if they failed, set a class
      rows[i].classList.add("invalid");              // to highlight the row
    } else {                                         // otherwise,
      rows[i].classList.remove("invalid");           // remove class
    }
  }
  if (!allOK) {          // if any row failed display a message
    alert("Please ensure that every student has three different subjects.");
    e.preventDefault();  // prevent default to stop form submission
  }
}
```

```css
.invalid { background-color: pink; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr align='center'>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="codialum[]" value="314" /><input type='text' name='al1[]' id='al1[]' value='Student1' /></td>
    <td><select name="optativa1[]" id="optativa1">
        <option value=43>Opt. Anglès</option>
        <option value=44>Opt. Biologia</option>
        <option value=45>Opt. Maths</option>
        <option value=46>Opt. History</option>
     </select>
    </td>
    <td><select name="optativa1[]" id="optativa1">
        <option value=43>Opt. Anglès</option>
        <option value=44>Opt. Biologia</option>
        <option value=45>Opt. Maths</option>
        <option value=46>Opt. History</option>
     </select>
    </td>
    <td><select name="optativa1[]" id="optativa1">
        <option value=43>Opt. Anglès</option>
        <option value=44>Opt. Biologia</option>
        <option value=45>Opt. Maths</option>
        <option value=46>Opt. History</option>
     </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr align='center'>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="codialum[]" value="314" /><input type='text' name='al1[]' id='al1[]' value='Student2' /></td>
    <td><select name="optativa1[]" id="optativa1">
        <option value=43>Opt. Anglès</option>
        <option value=44>Opt. Biologia</option>
        <option value=45>Opt. Maths</option>
        <option value=46>Opt. History</option>
     </select>
    </td>
    <td><select name="optativa1[]" id="optativa1">
        <option value=43>Opt. Anglès</option>
        <option value=44>Opt. Biologia</option>
        <option value=45>Opt. Maths</option>
        <option value=46>Opt. History</option>
     </select>
    </td>
    <td><select name="optativa1[]" id="optativa1">
        <option value=43>Opt. Anglès</option>
        <option value=44>Opt. Biologia</option>
        <option value=45>Opt. Maths</option>
        <option value=46>Opt. History</option>
     </select>
    </td>
  </tr>  <tr align='center'>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="codialum[]" value="314" /><input type='text' name='al1[]' id='al1[]' value='Student3' /></td>
    <td><select name="optativa1[]" id="optativa1">
        <option value=43>Opt. Anglès</option>
        <option value=44>Opt. Biologia</option>
        <option value=45>Opt. Maths</option>
        <option value=46>Opt. History</option>
     </select>
    </td>
    <td><select name="optativa1[]" id="optativa1">
        <option value=43>Opt. Anglès</option>
        <option value=44>Opt. Biologia</option>
        <option value=45>Opt. Maths</option>
        <option value=46>Opt. History</option>
     </select>
    </td>
    <td><select name="optativa1[]" id="optativa1">
        <option value=43>Opt. Anglès</option>
        <option value=44>Opt. Biologia</option>
        <option value=45>Opt. Maths</option>
        <option value=46>Opt. History</option>
     </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>Submit</button>
```

Obviously you can extend the `validate()` function to validate other things as required.

Note that your sample HTML is invalid because you've got an input element (the hidden one) inside the tr but *not* inside a td - you should move it into the first td.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Trying to put in my page. I will let you know if it worked as in this sample.